# Im using Wijimo text editor plugin and the librarys take too long to load - i need the JavaScript load time reduced or them loaded behind the scenes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I'm using Wijimo javascript text editor plugin and the library's are not loading in the correct order therefore theres a delay with the page loads and doesnt show the text editor fully loaded.

I have the javascript librarys stored at the bottom in my footer and the css files stored in the header for the custom editor that im using.

The javascript has been minimized and is stored locally.

The editor is a javascript plugin that im using

Im using mvc .net and using .cshtml.

Is there some ajax load or lazy loader that can preload these files behind the scenes so that when i load the page that has the text editor, it loads fully immediately?